# Reverse bit in python

Tags: python

Reverse bits of a given 32 bits unsigned integer.

For example, given input `43261596` (represented in binary as
`00000010100101000001111010011100`), return `964176192` (represented in
binary as `00111001011110000010100101000000`).

This does not work

```
def reverseBits(self, n):
    return int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Why my first approach does not work?

Comment: please edit your post with the question

Comment: Why do you imagine your input `43261596` should be rendered in binary with six leading zeroes? Your code isn't adding any leading zeroes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in assuming Python's `bin` produces a 32 bit aligned output. It doesn't; it outputs the smallest number of bits possible. Python 3's `int` type has an unbounded number of bits, and even in Python 2, `int` will auto-promote to `long` if it overflows the bounds of `int` (which is not related to the limits of C's `int`).

If you want it to act like a specific width, the easiest way is to use formatting tools with more control (which will also simplify your slice operation).

For example, by formatting to a fixed 32 characters wide, padding with zeroes, you get your desired result:

```
>>> int('{:032b}'.format(43261596)[::-1], 2)
964176192
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the output of `bin()`:

```
>>> bin(12345)
'0b11000000111001'
```

As you can see, it only outputs the first 14 ones and zeros. This is because it removes any leading zeros. Why does it do this? Well, python doesn't use a fixed size for integers like many other languages. The ints might be any number of bytes in practice, depending on the system and implementation.

So instead of `00000000000000001111111111111111` becoming `11111111111111110000000000000000`, it becomes `1111111111111111` instead